# How to attach a list box to a button onclick

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am creating a monthly calendar of events. Each day that has one or more events is represented by a button labelled with the day of the month. If the user clicks on a day with one event, that event is chosen. However if the user clicks on a button with more than one event, I would like to display a ListBox containing the event times. The user then chooses a time by clicking on a ListBox item.

Is this the way to go? Is there a "better" way to approach the problem?

The target is a mobile device. Language C#; OS Windows CE.

Comment: So you want to dynamically create and display a listbox in the form?

Comment: Do you want to be like a balloon?

Comment: @Jim - yes. The mobile device calendar contains only the days. The ListBox should act like a ContextMenu that is anchored to the bottom of the day button that was clicked.

Comment: @garzanti - I don't think so. It is not informative like a baloon (read tooltip) rather it needs to present choosable items, in this case the times of the event for that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not to use a ListBox at all. Rather, a number of Buttons, each labelled with one of the times, was collected into a Panel that was then positioned under the triggering day button. The BringToFront ( ) method was invoked against each Button as well as against the Panel. The Panel was Hidden, its controls were Cleared, and it was Disposed when one of the Buttons it contained was Clicked.